# Retrieve a List of Printers on the Network Using WMI, C#

Tags: c#, printing, wmi

I've developed a printer search application that search for all online printers on the network. Im referring to this site - [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=148)

The button event handler is something like:

```
private void btnGetPrinters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Use the ObjectQuery to get the list of configured printers
        System.Management.ObjectQuery oquery =
            new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");

        System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mosearcher =
            new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(oquery);

        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mosearcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            System.Management.PropertyDataCollection pdc = mo.Properties;
            foreach (System.Management.PropertyData pd in pdc)
            {
                if ((bool)mo["Network"])
                {
                    cmbPrinters.Items.Add(mo[pd.Name]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but it's not working. I've debugged by line an found that the ((bool)mo["Network"]) cond. return false. Anyone have idea why this happen? I've checked my network and printers conn. It's all working fine. please advice.